# Query to check MongoDB Current progress?

Tags: mongodb

I am started using MongoDB few days ago. Everything is fine with MongoDB but i couldn't figure out is query to check Current progress of MongoDB.  ie [ Command to check which query is currently in progress in MongoDB or Command to list out overall Process of MongoDB ]. I tried executing the command "mongostat" but it doesn't provides which query is in progress. So Please provide the remedy for this case.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to do mongo profiling:

[Database Profiling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)

You need to first turn on the profiler by selecting your database; than db.setProfilingLevel(2);

From there you can start tracking your queries.  If you haven't done so, I'd recommend installing MMS; mongo's monitoring system which is just an outstanding monitoring tool.

It's helped me a ton in watching queries come through.

Answer (score 7):

Use `db.currentOp()`. If it's not enough, try [profiling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Set Profiling =2 increase the load on sever like enabling general logs in MySQL.
It increase disk I/O.

So its better to monitor by db.currentOp(). Otherwise use profiling for a short period of time and disable it after logging few queries in logs.